# Problema ao gerar PDF com mPDF na hospedagem

Tags: php, servidor, composer, mpdf

É o seguinte, instalei o mPDF via composer para desenvolver o projeto localhost (no PC). Tudo funciona normalmente na máquina. Subi a pasta VENDOR para a hospedagem, mas não está gerando o PDF.
Alguém poderia me dar uma dica do que pode estar acontecendo?
A versão do PHP é a 7.2.7.

Erro no arquivo de log do servidor:

```
[01-Apr-2019 22:19:44 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
[01-Apr-2019 22:19:46 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mpdf\MpdfException' with message 'Unable to set PDF file protection, CSPRNG Functions are not available. Use paragonie/random_compat polyfill or upgrade to PHP 7.' in /home/transpomk/public_html/novo-website/sistema/libs/php/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Pdf/Protection/UniqidGenerator.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/transpomk/public_html/novo-website/sistema/libs/php/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(68): Mpdf\Pdf\Protection\UniqidGenerator->__construct()
#1 /home/transpomk/public_html/novo-website/sistema/libs/php/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1033): Mpdf\ServiceFactory->getServices(Object(Mpdf\Mpdf), Object(Psr\Log\NullLogger), Array, 0, Object(Mpdf\Language\LanguageToFont), Object(Mpdf\Language\ScriptToLanguage), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#2 /home/transpomk/public_html/novo-website/sistema/model/CreatePDF_01.php(105): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct(Array)
#3 /home/transpomk/public_html/novo-website/sistema/control/view-pdf.php(24): CreatePDF_01->solicitacaoPDF(Array)
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/transpomk/public_html/novo-website/sistema/libs/php/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Pdf/Protection/UniqidGenerator.php on line 11
```

Comment: Acesse o arquivo de log do seu servidor e veja qual é a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Erro nas permissões da pasta temporária, erro nas permissões do diretório de despejo das fontes da classe, erro de permissão no cache da classe, erro no seu código, enfim, pode ser qualquer coisa...

Comment: Em relação ao código poderia ser questão de caminhos e diretórios, no entanto, subi as pastar na mesma sequencia do localhost. Permissões podem até ser...

Comment: O próprio erro já acusa falta das funções `CSPRNG`. E ele ainda sugere um polyfill ou atualizar para o PHP 7: "*Uncaught exception 'Mpdf\MpdfException' with message 'Unable to set PDF file protection, CSPRNG Functions are not available. Use paragonie/random_compat polyfill or upgrade to PHP 7.' in*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução esta no próprio LOG:

> Unable to set PDF file protection, CSPRNG Functions are not available. Use paragonie/random_compat polyfill or upgrade to PHP 7

Se as funções CSPRNG não estão disponíveis é porque esta usando PHP5 e não PHP7 no servidor, essas funções só existem no 7

Soluções:

1. Altere para o PHP7 se a hospedagem permitir
2. Use esta biblioteca que adiciona as funcionalidades no PHP5: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Para instalar o `paragonie/random_compat` deve ser feito na máquina local, use o composer dentro da pasta do seu projeto em laravel:

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:\<9.99
```

O `:\<9.99`  é o suporte exclusivo para PHP5, se usar o comando assim:

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:\>=2
```

Irá suportar PHP5 mas também poderá ser usado com libs especificas para PHP7, no seu caso não parece ser a necessidade.

Comment: Guilherme, a versão do PHP da hospedagem é a 7.2.7

Comment: @RenatoDamazio se for então tem um BUG grave na tua hospedagem, faz assim, cria um arquivo chamado `info.php` na sua `public_html`, dentro desse arquivo adicione apenas isto `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, salve e então acesse o endereço da sua hospedagem assim `http://meusite.com.br/info.php` e veja qual é a versão do PHP, lembre-se, uma hospedagem pode oferecer diversas versões

Comment: realmente você estava certo. a versão que foi exibida é a PHP Version 5.6.40. Qual seria a melhor opção para eu resolver esse problema?

Comment: @RenatoDamazio se a hospedagem lhe permitir migre para o PHP7, geralmente tem como mudar no painel, se não use o `composer require paragonie/random_compat:\<9.99` e depois faça o upload do projeto novamente para a tua hospedagem.

Comment: postei outro erro que está agora. No entanto, fiz a atualização para o PHP7 no servidor.

Comment: @RenatoDamazio você quer exibir o PDF na tela ou quer salvar em um arquivo, se quiser exibir então tem algum texto ou HTML misturado ai no meio ou topo do documento que esta causando a falha.

Comment: resolvido! Era exatamente o que você mencionou acima. Havia códgo HTML misturado com PHP. Só ressaltando uma coisa também: Depois que retirei as tags HTML e deixei só as tags PHP, ele ainda ficou dando erro na linha 1 do arquivo, ai lembrei de ler em uma pesquisa que fiz, sobre retirar todos os espaços antes da abertura da tag PHP, fiz isso e agora está funcionando perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @RenatoDamazio por nada, se puder marque a resposta como sendo a correta. Obrigado